# McvMailer doesn't see views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, mvcmailer

I want to use MvcMailer in my application. I created a new class library project called MyMailer. Now I want to use it in my MVC app.

```
// mailer    
public class MyMailer : MailerBase, IEdoctorMailer  
{
    public MyMailer()
    {
        MasterName = "_Layout";
    }

    public virtual MvcMailMessage Invitation()
    {
        //ViewBag.Data = someObject;
        var msg = Populate(x =>
        {
            x.Subject = Labels.Invitation;
        x.ViewName = "Invitation";
        x.From = new MailAddress("xxx@gmail.com");
        x.To.Add("yyy@gmail.com");
        });

        return msg;
    }
}

//mvc controller
IMyMailer mailer = new MyMailer();
var inv = mailer.Invitation();
inv.Send(new DefaultSmtpClient()); // see below

public class DefaultSmtpClient : SmtpClient, ISmtpClient
{
    public DefaultSmtpClient() : base("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    {
        EnableSsl = true;
        UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential("login", "pass");         
    }

    public void SendAsync(MailMessage mailMessage)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

In MyMailer project in `Views/MyMailer/Invitation.cshtml` there is a file with some text in it.

When I send the email it actually arrives. But this Invitation view is not included (there's no body at all). I assume it's because the Send method is executed form the mvc project, but that's just my guess.

I even put a breakpoint in `Views/MyMailer/_Layut.cshtml --> RenderBody()`, but it never stepped into it.

What should I do to include the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're MvcMailer views are in a class library, you'll have to tell the MVC project where and how to find them by overriding the ViewEngine or VirtualPathProvider.

Comment: Can you please provide more details on how to do that?

Comment: This should put you on the right track. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4573845/1036187

Comment: You can also use this package to save you some time: https://github.com/mcintyre321/EmbeddedResourceVirtualPathProvider :)